# submit form data in html and send to server

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<form id="myform"><label for="name">Username:</label>
<input type="text" id="username" name="username">
<button id= "btnsub" onclick="registerUser();">Register</button></form>
<script> 
var url="http://localhost/rrrr/register.php?username="+ username;
var username ;      
function registerUser()
{ 
          document.getElementById("myform").action=url;
          alert("btn click") ;
          alert(username+'');
}
</script>
```

I tried above code, button click displays alert box as undefined what is the problem ?

Comment: What is the value for `username`? Where you have defined that variable?

Comment: sorry i defined that but forgot to mention here

Comment: Value for `username`?

Comment: @HrudayaPalwe Please post the latest version of your code here

Comment: `var url="http://localhost/rrrr/register.php?username="+ document.getElementById("username").value;` and `var username = document.getElementById("username").value;`

Answer (score 0):

if you use username directly it will be treated as javascript variable which not defined. for getting value of username input element.

you have to use like this

```
var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
var url="http://localhost/rrrr/register.php?username="+ username;

function registerUser()
{ 
          document.getElementById("myform").action=url;
          alert("btn click") ;
          alert(username+'');
}
```

for submitting form you can do like this

```
document.getElementById("myform").submit();
```

try this

```
<form><label for="name">Username:</label>
<input type="text" id="username" name="username">
<script> 
var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
var url="http://localhost/rrrr/register.php?username="+ username;

function registerUser()
{ 
          document.getElementById("myform").action=url;
          alert("btn click") ;
          alert(username+'');
document.getElementById("myform").submit();
}
</script>
<button id= "btnsub" onclick="registerUser();">Register</button></form>
```

Comment: use the script in head

Comment: you have to define the function before using it

Comment: it send the data in server side successfully, but still show those values undefined and second thing this code `document.getElementById("myform").submit();` redirect me on server and it displays page of server i want to avoid that page to display i want to be on same page of register .

Answer (score 0):

You need to define id in form tag to append action and also get "username" by id to append in url

```
<form><label for="name">Username:</label>
<input type="text" id="username" name="username">
<button id= "btnsub" onclick="registerUser();">Register</button></form>
<script> 
var username= document.getElementById("username").value;
var url="http://localhost/rrrr/register.php?username="+ username;

function registerUser()
{ 
          document.getElementById("myform").action=url;
          alert("btn click") ;
          alert(username+'');
}
</script>
```

Comment: use this $('#myform').attr('action',url); in place of this  document.getElementById("myform").action=url;

Comment: i found the solution above thnx for the suggestion but 1 problem is it still alerts undefined  ,but after "submit form "it redirects to the server and saves the values but in client side it displays page of server why ? how to avoid that page of server not to display on client side

Comment: You need to redirect another page to avoid display page of server

Comment: Is there any trick to remain on same page i mean on register page

Comment: what are you used cxf webservice or servlet?

Comment: actually i am using phpbb on server side i just need to send data phpbb will save it for me

Comment: You need to use "header('Location: mypage.php');" in phpBB to redirect on another page.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. To get the present `username` value.

Code snippets:

```js
function registerUser()
{
  var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
  var url="http://localhost/rrrr/register.php?username="+ username;
  //document.getElementById("myform").action=url;
  alert("btn click") ;
  alert(username);
}
```

```html
<form><label for="name">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>
<button id= "btnsub" onclick="registerUser();">Register</button></form>
```

Because if you define `username` and `url` outside the function, it will be holding the load time value only and it cannot be changed during button click action.

Comment: whenever i use `var username = document.getElementById('username').value;` this code it erases all the data of input fields and remain on same page

Comment: Please post a fiddle which reproduces your problem.

Comment: Main problem was it was not redirecting to server,  now it successfully saves my data on server side i used this document.getElementById("myform").submit(); still show undefined but not an issue .. as it saves required fields in database suggested by above reply now the problem is  , "submit form "redirects to the server and saves the values but in client side it displays page of server why ? how to avoid that page of server not to display on client side